# Как сохранить состояние приложения при закрытии вкладки

Tags: reactjs, form, localstorage

```
onSearchSubmit = async (searchInputValue) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${searchInputValue}&appid=f7ba517291e94b77301fa612e55f08b5`)
    this.setState({weatherResult: response.data})
 }

 componentDidMount(searchInputValue) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    searchInputValue = localStorage.getItem('state')
    this.onSearchSubmit(searchInputValue)
    });
  };
```

Есть простое приложение на React с формой, при закрытии приложения последние данные формы хранятся в loclalstorage, при запуски приложения пытаюсь отправить сохраненные данные в форму и вывести карточку но не получается